# How to get Spring XD working on Windows

Tags: spring, shell, command, spring-xd

After downloading Spring XD and extracting the folder in my program files I tried using the command: xd-singlenode. After doing so, Spring XD appears to work for only a couple a seconds and then sends the following error, which I am having trouble interpreting/solving for it:

```
C:\Program Files\spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE\xd\bin> xd-singlenode

 _____                           __   _______
/  ___|          (-)             \ \ / /  _  \
\ `--. _ __  _ __ _ _ __   __ _   \ V /| | | |    
 `--. \ '_ \| '__| | '_ \ / _` |  / ^ \| | | |
/\__/ / |_) | |  | | | | | (_| | / / \ \ |/ /
\____/| .__/|_|  |_|_| |_|\__, | \/   \/___/    
      | |                  __/ |
      |_|                 |___/
1.2.0.RELEASE                    eXtreme Data


Started : SingleNodeApplication
Documentation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki

2016-10-09T22:03:02-0400 1.2.0.RELEASE ERROR main boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.kohsuke.args4j.IllegalAnnotationError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:176) ~[args4j-2.0.16.jar:na]
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.addOption(CmdLineParser.java:131) ~[args4j-2.0.16.jar:na]
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:34) ~[args4j-2.0.16.jar:na]
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:91) ~[args4j-2.0.16.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:69) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:45) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:285) ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.ContainerBootstrapContext.<init>(ContainerBootstrapContext.java:48) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:57) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.main(SingleNodeApplication.java:50) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:170) ~[args4j-2.0.16.jar:na]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to match 'file:/C:/Program%20Files/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/bin/../lib/messagebus/kafka/' with regex '.*C:/Program Files/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/bin/../lib/messagebus/([^/]*).*'
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.init(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.java:101) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.<init>(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.java:58) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandlers$SingleNodeDataTransportOptionHandler.<init>(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandlers.java:52) ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.kohsuke.args4j.IllegalAnnotationError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:176)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.addOption(CmdLineParser.java:131)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:34)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.<init>(CmdLineParser.java:91)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:69)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.onApplicationEvent(CommandLinePropertySourceOverridingListener.java:45)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:285)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.ContainerBootstrapContext.<init>(ContainerBootstrapContext.java:48)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:57)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.main(SingleNodeApplication.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.createOptionHandler(CmdLineParser.java:170)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected to match 'file:/C:/Program%20Files/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/bin/../lib/messagebus/kafka/' with regex '.*C:/Program Files/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/bin/../lib/messagebus/([^/]*).*'
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.init(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.java:101)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.<init>(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandler.java:58)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.options.ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandlers$SingleNodeDataTransportOptionHandler.<init>(ResourcePatternScanningOptionHandlers.java:52)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with space escaping - a common problem with Java on Windows.

```
Program%20Files/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/...
```

Vs.

```
Program Files/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/...
```

I suggest you install in another folder (one with no spaces).

Also, the current version is 1.3.1; this may be solved there; but I generally recommend not using folders with spaces in them with Java to avoid this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to directory using command prompt.

```
Command: cd C:\tauseef_soft\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE
```

2- Set the environment variable XD_HOME

```
Command: set XD_HOME=C:\tauseef_soft\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd
```

3-  Go to directory xd/bin

```
Command:- cd C:\tauseef_soft\spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\xd\bin
```

4- Run xd-singlenode.bat from command prompt. 
Manually run by clicking xd-shell.bat 
Path: spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE\shell\bin
It will open new screen, where you need to work. in xd-singalnode promt you can see out put.